# Update a gridPane in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

In my `javafx` project I have got a ComboBox with several values. When my application begins I do the following:

```
gui.course_P = new ComboBox<String>();
    for (int i = 1; i < gui.columns.size(); i++) {
        gui.course_P.getItems().add(gui.columns.get(i));
}

gui.createTestButtonPane.add(gui.course_P, 2, 1);
```

Where `gui.columns` is a list of strings.

Meanwhile in the application this value can be changed. However since I have already add this comboBox to my GridPane and then to my scene when this value change (gui.columns) the new value did not displayed in the comboBox. Since I have already add the old gui.course. Is there a way to update the createTestButtonPane with the new gui.course_P?

**EDIT:**  What I am trying to do is to add the value on comboBox on a listener and then add it again to the gridPane:

```
String temp1 = course_name.getText();
gui.course_P = new ComboBox<String>();
gui.course_P.getItems().add(temp1);     
//gui.createTestButtonPane.add(gui.course_P, 2, 1);
```

The course is added properly to comboBox, but then when I add again the combobox to gridpane, I have as a result two comboBox. What I want is just to update the gui.course to my gridPane.

**EDIT2**: I followed the example of the answer post for my code.

```
    //gui.course_P =  new ComboBox<>(gui.columns);
    gui.course_P =  new ComboBox<String>();
    for (int i = 1; i < gui.columns.size(); i++) {
        gui.course_P.getItems().add(gui.columns.get(i));
    }
```

The problem is that I want everything from the list except the 1st element. 
When I am using `gui.course_P =  new ComboBox<>(gui.columns);` instead of the for loop it is working but I have for some reason two times the elements of the list and I got also the first item. Can I add it without the first item?

Comment: add a component or item listener to the combobox and if you then change a value remove the old one and add the new one

Comment: I add my question. I add the new value on listener but i want to update on the listener also the content of the gridPane.

Comment: can you remove the old one/overwrite it?

Comment: To delete it and re-write it again the course_P?

Comment: yeah thats what i mean

Comment: Just make `gui.columns` a `ObservableList<String>` and use `gui.course_P.setItems(gui.columns)` or create a `ListProperty<Sting> columns` and do `gui.course_P.itemsProperty().bind(columns)`, if the list needs to be swapped instead of modified.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer it does not solve the problem because the problem is that I have already add the gui.course_P in the gridPane so this is rendered in the gui. I want to re-rendered the combobox with the new values.

Comment: My proble is not with Combobox but with what I am rendering in the system. Because the initialization of comboBox is added before the chagne in the values, what I want is when I am having new values to render again the combobox in the gridPane I have!

Comment: That variables name that you have not helping at all... look how beautiful are on the answer of `Omid` ;(

Answer (score 3):

This works fine for me. Whenever the button is pressed, a new item gets added to `combobox`. I just used an `ObservableList<String>` as combobox's item property. There is no need for clearing or adding it again.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ComboBoxTest extends Application {
    private ObservableList<String> source = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Pane root = createPane();
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Pane createPane() {
        GridPane pane = new GridPane();
        Button addButton = new Button("add new item");
        addButton.setPrefWidth(150);
        addButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                source.add("Item" + source.size()); // editing the source
            }
        });

        ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<>(source);

        pane.add(addButton, 1, 0);
        pane.add(comboBox, 1, 1);
        pane.setPrefHeight(200);
        pane.setPrefWidth(200);
        return pane;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

---

**0 - Initial state:**

[image]

**1 - Button is pressed:**

[image]

**2 - Button is pressed again:**

[image]

Comment: I am getting errors when I am trying to convert my ArrayList to observable list. I cant import properly the libraries. Should download external jars for that?

Comment: No, it's pure Java 8 code. Maybe you have the wrong Java version (must be 8). I included `impotrs` in my code. I hope it helps. For converting `ArrayList` to `ObservableList`, there is a construcotr  for `FXCollections.observableArrayList` that accepts `Collection` and therefore `ArrayList`

Comment: The eclipse import auto complete didn't work properly.Now it works fine!

Comment: It works! However can I add source list  ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<>(source); without adding the first element?

Comment: Also when instead of adding my observable list directly to the combobox I try to add it with a for loop:gui.course_P =  new ComboBox<String>();
  for (int i = 1; i < gui.columns.size(); i++) {
   gui.course_P.getItems().add(gui.columns.get(i));
  }
It doesnt updated automatically!